# Complex? Dynamic SQL pivot table in c# with no aggregation

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

Bit of a rookie with c# and SQl but have come across a potentially tricky pivot table query that i'm unable to solve.

I have a database that looks like this:

| Number | Revision | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| J1234-S-CA-0001 | 00 | S9 | 01/01/2022 |
| H5678-C-TN-0005 | A2 | S0 | 05/09/2022 |
| X5274-X-SC-0012 | 05 | S4 | 06/07/2022 |
| J1234-S-CA-0001 | 01 | S4 | 06/09/2022 |

Which essentially tracks the issuing of documents - the document numbers, it's revision, status and the date it was issued.

The number, revision and status columns are of type NVARCHAR and need to remain as such as they're a mixture of text and numbers. I'd like to transform the database to produce the following result. A log of which revisions of the documents were issued on which days. Note the column headers will need to be set dynamically as the data source will be large and varying.

| Number | 01/01/2022 | 06/07/2022 | 05/09/2022 | 06/09/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| J1234-S-CA-0001 | 00 |  |  | 01 |
| H5678-C-TN-0005 |  |  | A2 |  |
| X5274-X-SC-0012 |  | 01 |  |  |

If possible, i'd also like to add two additional columns that show the revision and status of the most recent issue date, but I can live without this if it's too tricky/not possible.

| Number | Last Revision | Last Revision Status | 01/01/2022 | 06/07/2022 | 05/09/2022 | 06/09/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| J1234-S-CA-0001 | 01 | S4 | 00 |  |  | 01 |
| H5678-C-TN-0005 | A2 | S0 |  |  | A2 |  |
| X5274-X-SC-0012 | 01 | S4 |  | 01 |  |  |

So far I have tried the below, without much success - any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
DROP TABLE tbl_1

SELECT Number, Revision, Status INTO tbl_1 FROM documents

DECLARE @SqlQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(Max)

SELECT @PivotColumns = (SELECT DISTINCT [Date]) FROM documents

SET @SqlQuery = N'SELECT [Number], [Revision], [Status]' + @PivotColumns + '
                INTO TEMP
                FROM tbl_1 
                PIVOT(MAX([Revision])
                FOR 
                [Date] IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS Q'

EXEC sp_executesql @SqlQuery

SELECT * FROM TEMP
```

Comment: Your code looks like SQL Server but you've tagged `mysql`; how is `c#` relevant?

Comment: @Stu Apologies if i've tagged incorrectly or mis-explained. I'm working on a WPF app connected to a SQL database. For testing this specific query i've been querying the database directly but ultimately it will need to be executed in c#.

Comment: Code for MySQL:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot